# How can I add back the OnInit lifecycle hook and constructor when generating a component in Angular 15?

Tags: angular, constructor, command-line-interface, generate, ngoninit

I know it has been removed in the latest version, so you can add it manually, but i don't really want do copy and paste everytime I generate a component.

I've already found something at [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/301b5669a724261d53444d5172334966903078c0), but i can't seem to find the files. What should i tweak and how?

Comment: You really want to use Angular 15? If you want features of older version.

Comment: Your link just links to stackoverflow.com page. Did you mean to link to a specific question?

Comment: fixed the [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/301b5669a724261d53444d5172334966903078c0)